# Python Kivy Plyer FileChooser Freezes

Tags: python, kivy

I am working with Python Kivy and Plyer filechooser. When I run the function `filechooser.open_file()` on Linux, a file manager window opens up but then my editor, the file manager window, and my Kivy program all freeze. I have tried typing `pkill python` on the terminal, but it does not work. The only way I can figure out how to kill it is to reboot my whole computer. How can I prevent it from freezing or at least kill it properly so that I can debug without having to reboot my machine every time?

Main Python file:

```py
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.filechooser import FileChooserIconView
from kivy.utils import platform
from plyer import filechooser

class RootWidget(Widget):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

    def openFile(self):
        fc = filechooser.open_file()
        print(fc)
```

KV file:

```py
<RootWidget>
    BoxLayout:
        id: rootBox
        size: root.size
        orientation: 'vertical'
        Button:
            id: openfile
            text: "Open File"
            on_press: root.openFile()
```

Comment: I figured out If I am using VS Code, I can just run `pkill code` to kill the whole editor, which kills the app running from the editor. I still want to determine why its freezing though...